# Visual SVN Server Not Start service on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, svn, windows-server-2008, visualsvn-server

When trying to install visual svn in windows server 2008 gives the following error:

> VisualSVNServer.exe: Syntax error on line 20 of C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/VisualSVN Server/conf/httpd.conf: 
>  ServerRoot must be a
>   valid directory

and line 20 contains

```
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server"
```

Thanks

Comment: Is Visual SVN expecting forward slashes in the path instead of backslashes?

Comment: What VSVN Server version do you install? Is is a clean install or an upgrade? Is there anything special about "C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server" directory? Any other errors?

Comment: What about installing to another location? E.g. "C:\VisualSVN Server"

Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think Eric's comment is right (minus the `[foward|back]slash` mixup).  Try backslashes.

`ServerRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server"`

Comment: Forward slashes are OK, it's not the issue at all.

Comment: is a clean version, the path does not contain special characters and is the only error that throws.

Comment: I'd check if it was running as a service and as which user.  Could be UAC.  You could right-click on the program and choose Run as Admin and/or verify the service account has access to the directory.